# Using VM in CMS ActiveMQ

Tags: c++, content-management-system, virtual-machine, activemq-classic, interprocess

I am trying to to implement interprocess communication in my C++ project using ActiveMQ CMS library. For this matter I use the following URI:

failover:(vm:(broker:(tcp://localhost:6000)?persistent=false)?marshal=false)

Though it does not seem to work. The connection to broker stucks while waiting for a response from it. I think maybe VM protocol is not implemented in CMS. In fact  I could not find any "VM" string reference in CMS source code.

If so what is the best library for inter-process communication. I need consumer/producer pattern that works really fast.

Comment: I think only tcp is available for c++ clients

Answer (score 1):

There is no VM transport in CMS as there is no 'VM' since it is a C++ client.  You need to look into more standard mechanisms for interprocess communication.